# Matrix Vectorization for logical operation

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Given, l and r are two constants and arrays with dimensions like and :

U: n1 x 1

V: 1 x n2

R: n1 x n2

```
for i = 1:n1
    for j = 1:n2
        if R(i, j) > 0
            eij = R(i, j) - U(i, :).*V(:, j);
            U(i,:) = U(i,:) + l*(2*eij*V(:,j) - r*U(i,:));
            V(:,j) = V(:,j) + l*(2*eij*U(i,:) - r*V(:,j));
        end
    end
end
```

How can I vectorize this code? I tried:

```
E = bsxfun(@minus, R, U*V);
E(E<0) =0;
U(1:n1,:) = U(1:n1,:) + l*(2*E(1:n1, 1:n2)*V(:,1:n2)' - r*U(1:n1,:));
V(:,1:n2) = V(:,1:n2) + l*(2*U(1:n1,:)'*E(1:n1, 1:n2) - r*V(:,1:n2));
```

But this doesn't give me the same answer and since n1 and n2 are too large , running for loops is taking too much time.

Please help. Thanks!

Edit:
U = [0.3; 0.1 ; 0.15; 0.05 ; 0.2 ];

V = [0.35 0.45 0.15 0.05];

R = [5 3 0 1; 4 0 0 1; 1 1 0 5; 1 0 0 4; 0 1 5 4];

Comment: Please also post an explanation of what your code aims to do rather than just posting code and expecting people to interpret it

Comment: An example for `U,V,R` and what you expect.

Comment: I am trying to implement the matrix factorization of movie ratings. R is the movie ratings array contained in a .mat file with values from 1-5. U and V are random valued arrays.

Comment: You have data dependency there, so it won't be easy if not impossible. I would keep it as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Some information that you did not provide:

Do you want value of `R` that are `<= 0` (in a later step etc)?

This part `U(i, :).*V(:, j)` does not seem right: You intend to multiply element-wise two vectors and you use `.*` but the problem is the vector you provide is 1-length long! So it's useless. Are you sure you wanted this?

Anyway from your code I can deduce the following in order to vectorize your calculations:

```
Rold = R;
I = R <= 0;
R = R - U*V;
R(I) = Rold(I);
```

This method of course uses a lot of memory since it allocates R twice.

Comment: For the sample I used a 1-length vector.

Comment: The problem is that you should provide the actual dimensions of your matrices in order to get a working solution

Comment: Sorry @Eypros. Here are the actual dimensions: R: 500x1000, U: 500x1 and V: 1x1000. But I also have to perform the same calculations for U: 500x3 and V:3x500.

Comment: And I can't alter the R array. I'm using it for further caluclations.

Comment: If there is no problem with memory you can copy `R` to a new matrix and alter this one.